# Get the container type for a nested type using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class Test {
    public class InnerTest{}
}
```

Now have a `TypeInfo` object for `InnerTest`. How can I find out the `TypeInfo` object for Test from `InnerTest`?

The other way around is simple, I can just use `GetNestedTypes()`, but I can't find a method or property (other than `IsNestedType`) to figure out the containing class for a Nested Class.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can get this by retrieving the property "DeclaringType".

Quoting MSDN:

> A Type object representing the enclosing type, if the current type is a nested type; or the generic type definition, if the current type is a type parameter of a generic type; or the type that declares the generic method, if the current type is a type parameter of a generic method; otherwise, null.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're looking for [`Type.DeclaringType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, I want to add that it gets a bit complicated if generic types are involved, because the generic type arguments are defined on the Type of the inner instance not the `DeclaringType`.

Consider this class:

```cs
internal class WithGenericArg<T>
    {
        private T _data;

        public WithGenericArg(T data)
        {
            _data = data;
        }

        public class Internal
        {
            public int Foo()
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }

        public class Internal2<T2>
        {
            public T2? _data2;

            public Internal2(T2? data2)
            {
                _data2 = data2;
            }

            public T2? Foo2()
            {
                return _data2;
            }
        }
    }
```

When looking at the type of `Inner` its `IsGenericType` property is true and `GetGenericArguments()` returns 1 element (as well as `GenericTypeArguments` returns 1 element when the type is closed). This is the type argument (or concrete type) for the type argument of the outer(!) class.

When looking at the type of `Inner2` there are even 2 type arguments, one for the outer class and one for the inner.